# Linq duplicate elements when iterating over XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes'?>
    <stock-items>
      <stock-item>
        <name>Loader 34</name>
        <sku>45GH6</sku>
        <vendor>HITINANY</vendor>
        <useage>Lifter 45 models B to C</useage>
        <typeid>01</typeid>
        <version>01</version>
        <reference>33</reference>
        <comments>EOL item. No Re-order</comments>
        <traits>
          <header>56765</header>
          <site>H4</site>
          <site>A6</site>
          <site>V1</site>
        </traits>  
        <type-validators>
          <actions>
            <endurance-tester>bake/shake</endurance-tester>
          </actions>
          <rules>
            <results-file>Test-Results.txt</results-file>
            <file-must-contain file-name="Test-Results.xml">
              <search>
                <term>[<![CDATA[<"TEST TYPES 23 & 49 PASSED"/>]]></term>
                <search-type>exactMatch</search-type>
              </search>
            </file-must-contain>
          </rules>
        </type-validators>
      </stock-item>
    </stock-items>
```

Im trying to get the **rules** fragment from the xml above into a string so it can be added to a database.  Currently the **search** element and its contents are added twice.   I know why this is happing but cant figure out how to prevent it.

Heres my code

```
    var Rules = from rules in Type.Descendants("rules")
                                       select rules.Descendants(); 

              StringBuilder RulesString = new StringBuilder();

              foreach (var rule in Rules)
                    {   
                      foreach (var item in rule)
                      {      
                              RulesString.AppendLine(item.ToString());
                      }
                    }

 Console.WriteLine(RulesString);
```

Finally any elements in **rules** are optional and some of these elements *may* or *may not* contain other child elements up to 4 or 5 levels deep. TIA

**UPDATE:** 
To try and make it clearer what im trying to achieve.

From the xml above I should end up with a string containing *everthing* in the rules element, *exactly* like this:

```
<results-file>Test-Results.txt</results-file>
                <file-must-contain file-name="Test-Results.xml">
                  <search>
                    <term>[<![CDATA[<"TEST TYPES 23 & 49 PASSED"/>]]></term>
                    <search-type>exactMatch</search-type>
                  </search>
                </file-must-contain>
```

Comment: Need to get everything in rules into a string verbatim.  The sting will be stored in a database and will be processed as XML at a later stage.

Comment: as you have mentioned search element is getting added twice, once as part of file must contain, and secondly due to search element. What is your expected behavior for such elements. Do you want only element, and not the child elements to added for top level elements inside Rules

Comment: Objective is to extract the entire contents of the rules element as is while taking account that the rules element may or may not contains child elements several levels deep. For now I'm just trying to avoid duplicates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Objective is to extract the entire contents of the rules element as is while taking account that the rules element may or may not contains child elements several levels deep

If you just want the entirety of the `rules` element as a string (rather than caring about its contents as xml), you don't need to dig into its contents, you just need to get the element as an `XNode` and then [call ToString() on it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341005.aspx) :

> The following example uses this method to retrieve indented XML.
>
> ```
> XElement xmlTree = new XElement("Root",
>     new XElement("Child1", 1)
> );
> Console.WriteLine(xmlTree);
> ```
>
> This example produces the following output:
>
> ```
> <Root>
>   <Child1>1</Child1>
> </Root>
> ```

Comment: Already tried something similar but it doesnt work.  RulesString.Append(Rules.ToString());
Console.WriteLine(RulesString); prints junk

Comment: @Canacourse your current `Rules` variable is an *iterator* over all the descendants of the `rules` element. You don't need that. Just get the *single* `XElement` for the `rules` element, and call `ToString` on that.

Comment: Thanks got it with the single xelement. Should have thought of it earlier.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to prevent duplicates than you will need to use Distinct() or GroupBy() after parsing the xml and before building the string.

I'm still not fully understanding exactly what the output should be, so I can't provide a clear solution on what exactly to use, or how, in terms of locating duplicates. If you can refine the original post that would help.

1. we need the structure of the xml as it would appear in your scenario. nesting and all.
2. we need an example of the final string.
   saving it to a db doesn't really matter for this post so you only need to briefly mention that once, if at all.